# How to draw arrows pointing a desired position

Tags: arrows

I want to reproduce the following equation:
[image]

Do I need to use tikz package?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use the TikZ package, but it will simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

With TikZ you can use the `remember picture` option to make the defined nodes available in the whole document.  Then you can connect the two remembered nodes with an arrow by using the `overlay` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
$\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(A1.base)]\node[inner xsep=0pt] (A1) {$A$};
B
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(A2.base)]\node[inner xsep=0pt] (A2) {$A$};$
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[<->] (A1) -- +(0,-.5) -| (A2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

It is also possible to place this arrow with the capabilities of pure LaTeX.  Therefore I abuse the `array` environment.  Here you will have to adjust the width of the connecting rule each time the width of the cell with `B` changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
A & B & A \\
\uparrow & \hidewidth\rule[-2pt]{16pt}{.4pt}\hidewidth & \uparrow \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I guess TikZ package suits for me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do with `pst-node` and `auto-pst-pdf` (the latter to compile with `pdflatex`): define nodes in your equation, and connect them with an `\nc...` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{postscript}%
    \rnode{A0}{A}\enspace B\enspace \rnode{A1}{A}\enspace . \:. \:. \:.
    \ncbar[angle=-90, nodesep=2pt, linewidth=0.6pt, arrowinset=0.15, linejoin=1]{<->}{A0}{A1}
  \end{postscript}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This helps me to learn another way to do so.
Thanks a lot!